# Android Retrofit and bad data contract

Tags: android, retrofit

Normally RESTful end point returns one object or a list of said type object with some additional data for pagination purposes.

However, interesting case, the API I am working with will return a list of mixed type objects. For example:

```
{
  "media": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "oranges",
      "Some type specific property": "foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "apples",
      "Some type specific property": "bar"
    }
   ]
}
```

Is it possible for retrofit to accommodate this with reflection and properly pick out the different type of objects returned with the same key? (As in our example `media`)

The mobile application is already running in production mode, and what would be the least painful way to accommodate this API architecture?

Comment: yes this would work , creat java objects for this json and call the api using rettofit

Comment: How would retrofit being able to pick out what type of object to create within the media array? Since there are two different type of objects being returned.

Comment: you have to map the json to java object , I have posted the answer. Retrofit uses GSON internally to de serialize json to java object

Comment: I may have been unclear, but the objects in the media array maps to **different** Classes. How would Retrofit know which class to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create java object models

define your api using retrofit

```
public interface sampleApi {
@GET("/v1/endpoint")
void promoImages(Callback<CustomObject> callback);
```

Create Adapter

```
 RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.BASE_SERVER_ENDPOINT)
                .setClient(new OkClient(client));

 CustomApi api = builder.build().create(CustomApi.class);
```

Call api

```
  api.promoImages(callback);
```